# What is an appropriate water to yeast ratio for hydrating yeast for bagels?

Tags: baking, yeast, bagels

I've been doing a lot of bagel making lately... my bagels are "on point", except they aren't rising as much as you would see in a typical bagel shop... in fact, I've noticed they kind of "deflate" a little as time goes on.

Is there a liquid/yeast ratio I should consider when "hydrating" or "waking" my yeast? I'm thinking about adding another gram or 2 of yeast, but I don't want to "drown it"... I don't even know if that makes sense as a thing, but I thought I'd ask before I start wasting flour.

- 540g High Gluten (12-14%) Flour
- 140g Cold Water
- 7g Malted Barley
- 7g Fine Kosher Salt

-- Yeast Mixture--

- 7g Active Dry Yeast
- 20g Sugar
- 150g Warm Water

I let the yeast, sugar, and water "activate" for 20 minutes.

I put the "dry ingredients" into the mixer and mix them up... then I up the speed to medium and add the yeast mixture and the cold water... I mix for up to 4 minutes... then when a cohesive ball is formed I put it on a granite counter top and knead by hand for a further 3-5 minutes...

After that I let it rest covered with a damp dish cloth for a least an hour...

After resting... I punch down the dough... measure out equal portions... then I make rings...

I boil each bagel on each side for 1.5-2 minutes...

After boiling... egg wash, toppings, bake for 25-30 minutes on 425.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include the ratios and methods you are using at the moment, please? You have a very specific question (which is good), but with yeasted doughs, it’s good to look at the whole picture even when modifying only one aspect.

Comment: Btw. when I read “deflating” I immediately think “overproved”.

Comment: Ok... I've added ingredients

Comment: At what stage are they deflating, are you letting the shaped dough rise before boiling?

Comment: Yes... I put them into the refrigerator overnight... they just don’t ever get really “puffed up” like you would see at a bagel shop... then after we put them “away” maybe a couple of hours they start to “deflate”... don’t get me wrong they are still “bagel-like” with some “height”, but I’m looking for really thick bagels

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a step. You have to let them proof after forming them into rings. Just like how for bread making you always have to double proof, or else it'll be like pizza or pita dough.

After that they should be fine, just take care not to handle them too aggressively while moving to and from the boiling water (Again, just like bread. You deflate the first proofing intentionally but after the second proofing you have to maintain the air bubbles that make up your crumb)

Answer (score 1):

Your ingredients ratios are on point, same as I use. Be careful not to over-proof, it causes deflation. Also, you might not be kneading quite enough. I ran into these issues myself on my quest for the perfect homemade bagels.

Knead 15 minutes and proof at room temp (70° F) for 1 hour. Portion into nice rubbery balls and pinch them into rings. I find this technique easier with a drier dough. Let rest 10 minutes then stretch them a bit. At this point you could either put them in an airtight container in the fridge over-night, remove and go straight into the water bath. I do 20 seconds on each side otherwise they get too tough and also might deflate. I always leave overnight for morning bagels. Or you could leave on the counter to raise just a bit then into the bath. If left out on the counter for second raise, only let raise to 3/4 of full raise, otherwise they will deflate from the bath. I personally find they are more forgiving if left overnight in the fridge. In either case, after the bath they should go straight into a preheated oven.